# Include Android Play Services to APK

Tags: android, google-play-services

For an app I need to make use of google's play services for location purposes.

Is there any way to include the location service ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0') to the .apk so that the end user does not need to update the play services via play store if an older version is installed on the device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google play service is separate standalone app. Since its not opensource, we will not be able to use it part of your app's apk.

The part of google play code that we add in our app is merely an interface between our app and the google play services app.